# How do I write Foldable instance for this type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, fold

I have the following data type defined:

```
data SynthesisTreeResult comp a = CompNode (comp a) [SynthesisTreeResult comp a]
                                | InputLeaf Location
```

I want to be able to turn it into a list of type `[comp a]` using `toList`, which requires an instance of `Foldable`.

I tried to write an instance by implementing `foldMap`:

```
class Foldable f where
  foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
```

However, since `comp :: * -> *`, I have to write `instance Foldable (SynthesisTreeResult comp) where ...`, which causes `foldMap` to have following type

```
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> SynthesisTreeResult comp a -> m
```

But I need

```
foldMap :: Monoid m => (comp a -> m) -> SynthesisTreeResult comp a -> m
```

to be able to fold it.

Is it possible? Maybe I need to impose `Functor` on `comp`?

Comment: Hint, you can make it `instance Foldable comp => Foldable SynthesisTreeResult comp a`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hum, after thinking about this more, it turns out that this isn't exactly what I want. Such instance would allow me to fold `SynthesisTreeResult` into `a`, while I want `comp a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comment that you want a `comp a` instead of an `a`, you need to make a minor change to your type:

```
data SynthesisTreeResult t = CompNode t [SynthesisTreeResult t]
                           | InputLeaf Location
```

That's necessary because the type that comes out of `foldMap` is always the last type parameter of the type that went in. Fixing the usages of your type is easy; just change `SynthesisTreeResult Foo Bar` to `SynthesisTreeResult (Foo Bar)` everywhere. With that change, here's your `Foldable` instance:

```
instance Foldable SynthesisTreeResult where
    foldMap f (CompNode x xs) = f x <> foldMap (foldMap f) xs
    foldMap _ (InputLeaf _) = mempty
```

---

If that change to your type isn't acceptable, then you can't use `Foldable` to get what you want, and you need to write your own `toList` method, which you could do like this:

```
myToList :: SynthesisTreeResult comp a -> [comp a]
myToList (CompNode x xs) = x:concatMap myToList xs
myToList (InputLeaf _) = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) hint, I figured out the proper instance:

```
instance Foldable comp => Foldable (SynthesisTreeResult comp) where
  foldMap f (CompNode comp children) = mappend (foldMap f comp) $ mconcat $ map (foldMap f) children
```